# Cartan-Dieudonne Theorem in Hilbert space?

Tags: reference-request, hilbert-spaces, reflection

The Cartan-Dieudonne in $\mathbb{R}^n$ states that every orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix can be written as a product of at most $n$ reflections along hyperplanes.

My question is this: Is there a counterpart for infinite-dimensional real Hilbert space? Note that reflections along hyperplanes are defined there. Which isometries are (pointwise) limits of products of reflections? I assume this has been studied but I couldn't find anything. Any comments/reference would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cartan-Dieudonne theorem fails in infinite dimensions. An explanation given in *Advances in Ultrametric Analysis: 12th International Conference on $p$-adic Functional Analysis*, page 255, is that in infinite dimensions the isometry $-{\rm Id}$ cannot be written as a finite product of hyperplane reflections.

Comment: OK, thanks, I will try to get this book. Now as stated in my question, I didn't expect *finite* products but rather *limits of finite products*, i.e., an infinite product. Did they exclude limiting behaviour as well? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't know more details. I actually stumbled in this observation stating the trouble with infinite dimensions by chance, so I figured out I'd put the reference here.

Comment: This is actually nice, many thanks! If you take the normal vectors to be the standard unit vectors in $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$, then I think you do get $-\text{Id}$ in the limit. However, if you consider this in $\ell_2(\mathbb{R})$ which is not separable, then I think you will not get it as a sequential limit.